# Azure pipeline and DotNet core project: Unable to load the service index for source api.nuget.org

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines

I was given the task to create a pipeline on our Windows Self Hosted agent to build a DotNet Core project located on GitHub.

I have a pipeline that does that already and works well but using it with the second project, it fails with this message:

```
Determining projects to restore... 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [E:\Agent\_work\24\s\src\myProject\ myProject.csproj] 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Response status code does not indicate success: 302 (Moved Temporarily). [E:\Agent\_work\24\s\src\ myProject \ myProject.csproj] 
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

We have firewall constraints so we have setup an artifact feed with upstream source to Nuget, I cannot tell for sure that the project that works tries to use it but at least, it does not fail.  I am not the author of the projects and don’t use Nuget a lot, could I have some help finding what can be the issue?  Would it be burried in the Nuget files of the project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I added a nuget.config file to the solution with path to my feed with the upstream:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="REPO" value="https://...com//_packaging/REPO/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Used only this in my YAML:

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'Step 1: Authenticate with NuGet'
```